Can't connect model with armature
I added Human Meta-Rig, fit it to my model, applied all transforms on bones by CTRL A, then press Generate Rig. After that select my model, then rig and CTRL P > With automatic weights. And my Mac just freezes in waiting for too long

I also tried to clean up every separate mesh by Degenerate Dissolve


200K vertices are too much for animating a character with ease: probably if you let your Mac run for a longer time it will be able to perform the parenting, but you will have problems of lagging during animation process, as realtime animating too many vertices is heavy for the machine.
The "correct" procedure is to perform a Retopology, creating a LoPoly version of the character (tipically from 3K to 30K vertices), baking all lost details onto a Normal Map, and parenting the LoPoly character to the rig.
Using decimate modifier or others automatic procedures to reduce the PolyCount leads generally to a loss of quality, but it can work sometimes, depending on the general quality requests.
